# TypeError when trying to plot a combined geopandas geodataframe

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have `GeoDataFrame` that I am trying to plot in relation to 4 reference points. I'm creating the reference points as part of a separate `GeoDataFrame`, combining them and then trying to plot the result. I am using the following code:

```
import pandas
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point

def dfTogpdf(df):
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Lon, df.Lat)]
    df = df.drop(['Lon', 'Lat'], axis=1)
    crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

    return GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)


habitat = gpd.read_file('desktop/species_19377/species_19377.shp')

latitude = [90, -90, 0, 0]
longitude = [0, 0, -179, 180]
frame = dfTogpdf(pandas.DataFrame({'Lat': latitude, 'Lon': longitude}))

framed = gpd.sjoin(frame, habitat,  how="inner", op='intersects')
framed.geometry.plot()
```

However this gives me the following error: `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

I am able to plot `habitat` and `frame` without any issue, but after they have been combined, I am left with an empty `GeoDataFrame` and not able to plot the result. Is there an extra step I need to take to plot my combined `GeoDataFrames`?

[species_19377.shp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xa4KTcXGVeL2z7Y7mIKxo-NVg-AhjZbf)

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:798: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = getattr(x, name)(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-255-31bfbe140734>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Alec/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alec')

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Alec/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    framed.geometry.plot()

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 253, in plot
    return plot_series(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py", line 273, in plot_series
    poly_idx = np.asarray((geom_types == 'Polygon')

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 861, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)

  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 800, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

`habitat.head()`:

```
             ID_NO        BINOMIAL  PRESENCE  ORIGIN COMPILER  YEAR  \
index_right                                                           
0            19377  Ratufa bicolor         1       1     IUCN  2008   
1            19377  Ratufa bicolor         1       1     IUCN  2008   
2            19377  Ratufa bicolor         1       1     IUCN  2008   
3            19377  Ratufa bicolor         1       1     IUCN  2008   
4            19377  Ratufa bicolor         1       1     IUCN  2008   

                                                      CITATION SOURCE  \
index_right                                                             
0            IUCN (International Union for Conservation of ...   None   
1            IUCN (International Union for Conservation of ...   None   
2            IUCN (International Union for Conservation of ...   None   
3            IUCN (International Union for Conservation of ...   None   
4            IUCN (International Union for Conservation of ...   None   

            DIST_COMM    ISLAND SUBSPECIES SUBPOP TAX_COMMEN  \
index_right                                                    
0                None   Con Son       None   None       None   
1                None      None       None   None       None   
2                None      Bali       None   None       None   
3                None      None       None   None       None   
4                None  Billiton       None   None       None   

                        LEGEND  SEASONAL  \
index_right                                
0            Extant (resident)         1   
1            Extant (resident)         1   
2            Extant (resident)         1   
3            Extant (resident)         1   
4            Extant (resident)         1   

                                                      geometry  
index_right                                                     
0            POLYGON ((106.6621000000001 8.752335593000055,...  
1            POLYGON ((113.1460000000001 -8.175164407999944...  
2            POLYGON ((115.2932000000001 -8.102764407999928...  
3            POLYGON ((97.17740000000003 2.226135593000038,...  
4            POLYGON ((107.8088000000001 -2.535364406999975...
```

`framed.head()`:

```
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [geometry, index_right, ID_NO, BINOMIAL, PRESENCE, ORIGIN, COMPILER, YEAR, CITATION, SOURCE, DIST_COMM, ISLAND, SUBSPECIES, SUBPOP, TAX_COMMEN, LEGEND, SEASONAL]
Index: []
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the error traceback.

Comment: Your shapefile gives an error when opening (in QGIS/ArcGIS): `species_19377.shp is not a valid or recognized data source`. Your data may be corrupted.

Comment: This is my first time working with shapefles, and I actually don't have any GIS software. However, as mentioned in the question I am able to plot the data from it with geopandas and interact with it fully through the module. It's the result of `sjoin` that I can't plot

Comment: Oo. you shared just `.shp` file. Shapefile consists of different files in same name. Could you add outputs of `habitat.head()` and `framed.head()` to your question.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I've altered my script to specify the directory instead of the .shp file, however all output seems the same.

Comment: Your points are probably out of habitat polygons, so that you get empty GeoDataFrame. Please upload all files of shapefile (shapefile consists of different files with same name and with extensions named .shp, .dbf, .prj, etc.),  So just one '.shp' file is useless.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I was not aware. I have edited the link so that it now contains all of the files that I have. Indeed, the points are out of the habitat polygons. Is there a way to join them regardless?

Comment: A "spatial join" joins attributes (columns) of different dataframes based on a relationship between the geometries of both dataframes. So it does not "join" or combine the actual geometries. If you want to do that, you should rather look at the `overlay` function (http://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/set_operations.html), or possibly even simpler `pd.concat` the two dataframes.

Comment: @joris Excellent! That is exactly the information I needed! If you post this an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to plot an empty GeoSeries, as evidenced by your post:

```
>>> framed.head():
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [geometry, index_right, ID_NO, BINOMIAL, PRESENCE, ORIGIN, COMPILER, YEAR, CITATION, SOURCE, DIST_COMM, ISLAND, SUBSPECIES, SUBPOP, TAX_COMMEN, LEGEND, SEASONAL]
Index: []
```

The `TypeError` is being triggered by the fact that this is an empty GeoDataFrame; the plotting code did not expect this edge case.  [This was a known bug](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/565) and has been fixed, but the geopandas project hasn't had a new release since then.  If you really need it fixed, you will have to install bleeding-edge geopandas from the source on GitHub.

But on the other hand, maybe you're looking in the wrong place.  Perhaps you didn't expect an empty result from the spatial join?

Comment: Right, I did not expect an empty result. I have edited the question to reflect this.